How can I cache a web page and show that page if there is no internet?
I'm using the package webview_flutter to load webview in the app. What I want to achieve is to show a cached webpage if there is no internet. How is that possible in Flutter using webview?
Here's my code
  final connectivity = await Connectivity().checkConnectivity();
  // ignore: unrelated_type_equality_checks
  if (connectivity == ConnectivityResult.none) {
    _loadOfflinePage();
  } else {
    _loadLivePage();
  }
} catch (e) {
  debugPrint(e.toString());
}


  _loadLivePage() async {
    try {
      final cache = DefaultCacheManager();
      await cache.downloadFile('url');
      await _webViewController.loadRequest(Uri.parse('url'));
    } catch (e) {
      _loadOfflinePage();
      debugPrint(e.toString());
    }
  }

  _loadOfflinePage() async {
    try {
      final cachemanager = DefaultCacheManager();
      final cachedFile =
          await cachemanager.getFileFromCache('url');
      if (cachedFile != null) {
        final cachedInfo = cachedFile.file;
        await _webViewController.loadFile(cachedInfo.path);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint(e.toString());
    }
  }

For caching I'm using flutter_cache_manager.
What is the correct way of doing this? Are there any alternatives?
